# Update BindingSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

[image]

I have bind 2 separate tables using BindingSource. Left grid contains student table and the right grid contains the timetable table.

I want to default the student foreign key based on the selected student in timetable table.

I can't find the event on which I should set the foreign key and how to save that change back to table.

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do, are you doing an update on the right grid that will impact the left grid or vice versa?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Found my answer from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c12c1kx4.aspx I was trying to set the foreign key in the detail table based on the selection on header.

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer and accept it.  Then people will be able to easily use it if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not being clear. Found my answer from msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c12c1kx4.aspx I was trying to set the foreign key in the detail table based on the selection on header.